# List Files which don't contain a particular string at a particular line

Tags: text-processing, awk, find

I am trying to find all files with extension `.md`

```
find . -type f -name "*.md"
```

Then I want to filter out those files whose 2nd line (line number = 2) doesn't contain this exact string beginning and ending with`author: Mr. Xab Ycd`

How can I do the second part? Doing `grep` would be inefficient as it checks the entire file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -type f -name '*.md' -exec \
  sh -c 'sed 1d\;q "$1" | grep -qvx "author: Mr. Xab Ycd"' sh {} \; -print
```

The above command includes all of the requirements without having to pass potentially-confusing filenames through shell pipes.

The first piece is copied as-is (almost) from yours -- look for files named `*.md`. I've changed the double-quotes to "hard" single-quotes; there's no functional difference in your case, but if you wanted to look for files named `*.$md` then double-quotes would attempt to expand the variable `$md`.

Matching filenames are then passed through another test via `-exec`. The parameter to exec is a small shell script whose job is to determine success or failure of the given filename in `$1`. The `sed` command prints only line two; there are different ways to do it, such as:

- `sed -n '2{p;q;}'` or
- `sed '1d;q`

The first says "don't print lines by default, but when you see line two, print it then quit".  The second says "print lines by default, but delete line one, quitting after that (on line two); the `q` command will print the current buffer before exiting.

That line of text (if any) is passed to grep, who checks to see if the entire line matches (or not) the given text. If it does *not* match (`-v`), then the whole command succeeds and thus `find` prints the filename.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Print does it nicely.

Comment: @Nikhil great! Just be careful if someone names a file `firstpart$'\n'secondpart.md`

Comment: With GNU sed, you could maybe avoid the shell + grep by quitting directly with an exit status? `-exec sed -n '2 {/^author: Mr. Xab Ycd$/q1; q0;}' {} \; -print`

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type f -name '*.md' -exec awk '
    FNR == 2 && $0 == "author: Mr. Xab Ycd" { exit 1 }
    FNR >  2 { exit 0 }' {} ';' -print
```

This would use `awk` to filter out any file that is at least two lines long and has a second line that is exactly the string that you mentioned. It does this by explicitly exiting with a non-zero exit status if the second line (`FNR == 2`) is exactly equal to the string.  It also exits with a zero exit status if reaches any line after line two as to not parse more than necessary.

The `find` command will proceed to print the pathname of the file with `-print` if `awk` exits with a zero exit status (the string was not found on line two).

Comment: The usage of the line counter `FNR` is superfluous here,  as you are making `awk` operate on file-at-a-time.

Comment: How would this treat single-lined files and empty files ? Would it not print them...

Comment: @RakeshSharma It would print them as they do not contain the string on their second line. And yes, you may save a character by removing the `F` from `FNR` if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
by_Xab() {
  local line
  {
    IFS= read -r line &&
      IFS= read -r line &&
      [[ $line = "author: Mr. Xab Ycd" ]]
  } < ${1-$REPLY}
}
printf '%s\n' **/*.md(D.^+by_Xab)
```

That reads at most 2 lines for each file and doesn't execute any command (it's all builtins) so would be a lot more efficient than `find -exec` approaches that run one command or more per file.

With GNU `awk`, you could do:

```
STRING='author: Mr. Xab Ycd' find . -name '*.md' -type f -exec gawk '
  BEGINFILE {found = 0}
  FNR == 2  {found = $0 == ENVIRON["STRING"]; nextfile}
  ENDFILE   {if (!found) print FILENAME}' {} +
```

Which would run one `find` invocation and with the `-exec ... {} +` syntax as few `gawk` invocations as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `awk` is the right tool for the job but *I do not know Awk*. Nonetheless, the following answer works using **Bash** with the `globstar` shell option enabled (`shopt -s globstar`).

```bsh
prompt% awk 'FNR==2 {print FILENAME, $0}' **/*.md | grep -v 'author: Mr. Xab Ycd' | cut -f1 -d ' '
```

`awk` displays the second line of all files named `*.md` in the current directory or in subdirectories and `grep` filters out filenames that do not include the specified string.

Answer (score 0):

When `find` supplies one file at a time and the onus of printing is with `find`:

```
find . -type f -exec perl -lne '$. == 2 && exit +/^author: Mr\. Xab Ycd$/' {} \; -print
```

here `find` supplies files in a bunch and the task of printing is handled by `perl`:

```
find . -type f -size 0 -print -o -exec perl -lne '
   print $ARGV if $. == 2 && !/^author: Mr\. Xab Ycd$/;
   close(ARGV),next if $. == 2;
   print($ARGV),close(ARGV) if eof;
' {} +
```

The **close**-*ing* off of **ARGV** is essential OTW the line counter, aka, **$.** isn't initialized for the upcoming file.

Note that the eof clause is needed OTW the 2nd line would never be reached for files of length > 1 and the check for the 2nd line would never happen.